# Solving a mathematical series inequality with mathematica

Tags: series-expansion

I have to show that a_n >= b_n for N{0}, Knowing that a > 0 and b > 0.
See the picture

[image]

How can I show the inequality with mathematica? Here is what I tried, but it didn't work (I began Mathematica one day ago)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Prove the induction step. This will allow us to know that no matter the `n`, so long as `a[n]>0` and `b[n]>0`, then `a[n+1] >= b[n+1]` by substituting in their definitions.

```
FullSimplify[(a[n] + b[n])/2 >= 2/(1/a[n] + 1/b[n]), {a[n] > 0, b[n] > 0}]
```

> True

We should also prove that the precondition of `a[n]>0` and `b[n]>0` implies that `a[n+1]>0` and `b[n+1]>0`, just so that we don't have any surprises during induction.

```
FullSimplify[(a[n] + b[n])/2 > 0, {a[n] > 0, b[n] > 0}]
FullSimplify[2/(1/a[n] + 1/b[n]) > 0, {a[n] > 0, b[n] > 0}]
```

> True
>
> True

Then by considering the condition that `a[0]>0` and `b[0]>0`, the application of induction shows that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ that $a_{n+1} \ge b_{n+1}$. Thus, so long as $a_0\ge b_0$ or $n\ge 1$, $a_n\ge b_n$.

Note that $a_0$ may be less than $b_0$, however.

Showing this directly in *Mathematica* is a bit trickier, however.

Comment: This relation is true in both situations: a>b , b>a, a=b. Maybe I can do your first step, and then proove that a[n] is > 0 for every n, and same for b[n] ??

Comment: @nolw38: So long as $n \ge 1$, $a_n \ge b_n$, regardless. But $a_0$ and $b_0$ are independent, that's all I was trying to point out.

Comment: Ok Thanks and sorry! As I am new in Mathematica, can you explain to me the utility of FullSimplify?

Comment: @nolw38 In this case, I am using `FullSimplify` to reduce mathematical expressions to the simplest forms _Mathematica_ can find. The first argument is the expression to be simplified, while the second argument is the assumptions that can be made while simplifying. In this case, all 3 of these statements simplify to `True`, meaning that so long as the assumptions are satisfied, they are always true.

Comment: Ok I understand! So, to prove than a[n] and b[n] are > 0, for n > 0, is there a simple way to show it? BTW, why didn't it work with RSolve?

Comment: @nolw38 Aside from manually noticing the induction, I haven't been able to. _Mathematica_'s fairly capable of proving individual expressions, but this is closer to the realm of automated theorem proving. Most such systems require significant hand holding. Perhaps someone else will be able to provide a more automated answer than this, however. I tend to rely on _Mathematica_ only to explore the individual steps of a problem like this, rather than making overarching proofs.

Comment: Wouldnt it be:  FullSimplify[(a[n] + b[n])/2 > 0, {a[n-1] > 0, b[n-1] > 0}]  and  FullSimplify[2/(1/a[n] + 1/b[n]) > 0, {a[n-1] > 0, b[n-1] > 0}] ??

Comment: @nolw38 don't use answers as a follow-up questions. Do you have something to add? Edit the question. Do you have a separate question, create a new topic.

Comment: @nolw38 There's nothing linking those assumptions to the actual formulas there. Expanding the formulas back a step is equivalent to the corresponding steps in my answer. However, those two steps, or the three steps in my answer, are not automatically a proof of the property in question. They are sufficient when combined with an understanding of induction, but _Mathematica_ generally won't do that automatically.